# About normal families of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

Let be $\Omega$ a compact subset of $H(D)$, i.e., the holomorphic functions in the open set $D$.
If $z_0 \in D$, then there exists a function $g \in \Omega$ such that:

$|g'(z_0)| \geq |f'(z_0)|$ for every $f \in \Omega$

Why? I think it must be a consequence of Montel's Theorem, but I don't know how.

Comment: There is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\Omega$, such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigl\lvert f_n'(z_0)\bigr\rvert = \sup \:\bigl\{ \bigl\lvert f'(z_0)\bigr\rvert : f \in \Omega \bigr\}\,.$$ Now, what do Montel and Weierstraß tell us?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Could one also argue that $\Omega \ni f \mapsto |f'(z_0)|$ is a continuous function, and therefore attains its maximum on the compact set? Is Montel's theorem still needed?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, but only after one has some experience with the topology of function spaces. So roughly, not before 1927 or so.